# aws s3 cp not working as user_data bootstrap script

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I start an instance (with user_data/bootstrap script) which creates a tar and then runs:

```
aws s3 cp /home/ubuntu/xy.tar s3://mybucket/
```

then I also tried running:

```
aws s3 cp /home/ubuntu/xy.tar s3://mybucket/ > /home/ubuntu/awslog
```

which yields an empty file (which it shouldn't if it would have worked)

When I then login to the server, the command works just fine. I made the bucket writable by everyone, and the AMI has `aws config` CLI setup with my key/secret.

What could I be missing?